# How to extract unique records of each student using AWK?

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I am trying to process the students feedback file.

Scenario:

- **5th and 6th character is sutdent id**
- **One student can give multiple feedback**
- **Extract first feedback of each student**

students_feedback.txt:

> 288Y**10**2RZDBPX1000000001dhana
>   10Q1**15**W4ZEAV18LXNPSPGRTTIDHBN1000000005egw JP2F1164EI1000000002d
>   EU9V**10**3IXI1000000003dfg1000000001dfdfds
>   XATS**11**SSSFOO4dhanaUXIBB7TF71000000004adf
>   10Q1**15**W4ZEAV18LXNPSPGRTTIDHBN1000000005egw

**Approach I tried:**

I thought of creating an array to specify the student id (Because I can give specific student's feedback) and reading the file by awk & extract stud id. After reading line by line I am checking the stu id against the array of stu id to create the stu_found array.

```
BEGIN { 
    Studnet_Ids = "10,11,12,13";
    n=split(Studnet_Ids,array,",");
    count = 0;
    delete Stu_Found[0];
} 

{
    StuId=substr($0,5,2)
    n=length(array);
    if(length(array) !=0 && (StuId in array)){
         for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            if(array[i] == StuId){
            Stu_Found[count++]=StuId;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I am stuck up here whether my approach is correct or is there any better approach to do this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!a[substr($0,5,2)]++' file

288Y102RZDBPX1000000001dhana
10Q115W4ZEAV18LXNPSPGRTTIDHBN1000000005egw JP2F1164EI1000000002d
XATS11SSSFOO4dhanaUXIBB7TF71000000004adf
```

a non-awk solution can be (id's will be sorted in the output)

```
$ sort -s -k1.5,1.6 file | uniq -s4 -w2

288Y102RZDBPX1000000001dhana
XATS11SSSFOO4dhanaUXIBB7TF71000000004adf
10Q115W4ZEAV18LXNPSPGRTTIDHBN1000000005egw JP2F1164EI1000000002d
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ll try and update the status.